# Windows 10 with Ubuntu 18.04 dual boot using grub2 - Reisntall windows without messing grub

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2

I have Windows 10 and Ubuntu 18.04 on two different ssds. Right now dual boot is working fine with grub bootloader. I need to reinstall windows 10 on the first SSD but I don't want to mess grub and definitely don't want to lose any of the data from my Ubuntu SSD. Is this possible? I am really confused by the most of the answers found on the web.

Comment: If grub is installed on the SSD with Windows, I doubt it. That said, it isn't too important not to "mess grub". It is easy to reinstall with [BootRepair tool](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair).

Comment: Hard to go wrong if you unplug your Ubuntu drive before proceeding. If grub does not boot with the Ubuntu drive removed, you don't have to worry about reinstalling it..

Comment: I 'll try using bootrepair tool, thanks for the suggestion